# Can we permanently prune Tensorflow low magnitude weights?

Tags: tensorflow, layer, tf.keras

I have a TensorFlow model where I can apply the pruner.prune_low_magnitude layer to the output of my Dense layers. This seems to work according to the instructions, and I get almost the same results down to 95% sparsity. The Processing time in GPU and CPU seems to be the same. It seems the pruning layer is calculating all the weights, then setting the smallest weights to zero to fit the sparsity figure. Is this right?

It would be nice to get a speed-up, of course, but for my present purposes, this is fine.

I would like to prune the weights and have them stay zero thereafter. I would prune some weights; then continue training to allow the model to recover from the pruning; then prune a bit more. I feel this should be a bit closer to what real neurones do. Is there some way of doing this?

My solution (which does not work yet) is to add a custom layer with Trainable=false. This has a mask array that starts off as all ones, and is set to zero if the corresponding weight is zero. The layer multiplies the weights by this mask array, so once a weight goes to zero, it will stay zero. Should this work? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be nice to get a speed-up, of course, but for my present
> purposes, this is fine.

To get a reduction in inference time, the op (Dense in your example) implementation needs to be able to take advantage of the sparsity and the particular hardware on which it runs.
The Tensorflow runtime on CPU/GPU does not support this yet, but TFLite does. The
[Pruning for on-device inference w/ XNNPACK](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_for_on_device_inference) tutorial demonstrates that.

> I would like to prune the weights and have them stay zero thereafter.
> I would prune some weights; then continue training to allow the model
> to recover from the pruning; then prune a bit more. I feel this should
> be a bit closer to what real neurones do. Is there some way of doing
> this?

This is the responsibility of the pruning schedule that is passed as argument to `prune_low_magnitude()`.

Existing implementations, such as [`ConstantSparsity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/ConstantSparsity) or [`PolynomialDecay`](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/api_docs/python/tfmot/sparsity/keras/PolynomialDecay) perform what you described: prune only at some steps and let the model recover in between. The `begin_step`, `end_step`, and `frequency` arguments let you control when and how frequently the pruning is applied during training.

> My solution (which does not work yet) is to add a custom layer with
> Trainable=false. This has a mask array that starts off as all ones,
> and is set to zero if the corresponding weight is zero. The layer
> multiplies the weights by this mask array, so once a weight goes to
> zero, it will stay zero. Should this work? Is there a better way?

This is basically how Tensorflow Model Optimization does it under the hood: [pruning_impl.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/model-optimization/blob/master/tensorflow_model_optimization/python/core/sparsity/keras/pruning_impl.py). You just need to apply `prune_low_magnitude()` as per the [Pruning with Keras tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras).

Comment: I have investigated prune_low_magnitude(). I think the back propagation behaves as though prune_low_magnitude() was not there, and then removes the lowest weights. So a weight that was not there in one iteration can come back. What I am trying to write is something more like a Disentangled VAE (a term I have only recently found).